# How to create my own AR engine: AR theory

Tags: android, ios, augmented-reality

I'm an iOS and Android developer and I want to create my own AR engine.

I've been using iOS ARToolkit but it is a mess! Code it is not optimized and I want to do it by my own.

The first thing is to understand how can I show a text over a mountain, for example, saying its name. In other words, I need to know how using device camera, user location and orientation and object location; I can show a label over that object on camera's image.

Do you know any book or website talking about AR theory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the AR example you mentioned, (Example: display the name of the mountain when suer see it on the screen through camera), three factors are used: User location, Orientation (you can use vertical orientation as well if it applies) and distance.

The logic is this: From your current "location" in the "direction" you are looking, if the mountain is within the specified "distance" then the program assumes you are looking at the mountain.  Camera image does not come into picture really.

Your supporting database within your device, know the exact distance to that mountain (can compute from the your current location and mountain's coordinates, which is in your database). You can display the distance on your screen too in order to provide more information (and better user experience).